# After using Eloquent to get a collection, can I change the location of a single object in that collection?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

First I need to explain to you what I'm trying to achieve. I am trying to return all `$categories` to a view which is used for editing images so that I can put those `$categories` in the select element BUT have the $category in which this image belong at the top. I've tried to do this several different way and each gives me quite a lot of headaches. Let me give you an example.

My main problem is that I need the first select element to be the current $category of the image so that if the user doesn't select a different element, the $category of the image wouldn't change.

This is how my previous attempt went:

1. I made a query that gets all categories except the one with $image->category_id.
2. Then I made another query that gets me only the category with $image->category_id ( I know this query is almost useless but I needed the name of that category as well )
3. I send that variables to the view
4. I used the variables in the view

My code was something like this ( I've cut some code that is irrelevant to the isseu):

```
public function updateArtwork($id){
    $image = Image::where('id', $id)->first();
    $imageCategoryId = $image->category_id;
    $categories = Category::where('id', '!=', $imageCategoryId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    $imageCategory = Category::where('id', $imageCategoryId)->first();
    $imageCategoryName = $imageCategory->name;

    return view('updateArtwork', ['image' => $image, 'categories' => $categories, 'imageCategoryId' => $imageCategoryId, 'imageCategoryName' => $imageCategoryName]);
}
```

And then I used it like this in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class='label required' for="artwork-category">Category</label>
    <select class='category-select' name='artwork-category' value='{{ Request::old('artwork-category') }}'>
            <option value='{{ $imageCategoryId }}'>{{ $imageCategoryName }}</option>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value='{{$category->id}}'>{{$category->name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

I have so many issue with how I've done this. First of all, I make 2 queries in order to check the category to which the image belongs and the categories in which it doesn't. Then I have to send loads of variables to the view and then use them in the view. I also need to check if those variables exists since if the image doesn't have a category, my code goes haywire and stuff like that.

This is why I've been wondering whether I could solve all those problems just using eloquent. Is it possible to do this:

1. Get all categories in descending order.
2. Then put a category with a certain id at the start of the collection ( so that it would be the first element to appear in the select box ) but still follow descending order after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all items except the matching id ordered by desc created at timestamp, then [prepend](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-prepend) the item to the collection:

```
$collection = Category::where('id', '!=', $id)->orderByDesc('created_at')->get();
$collection->prepend(Category::find($id);
```

Or use [partition](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-partition):

```
list($collection, $matched) = Category::orderByDesc('created_at')->get()->partition(function ($item) use ($id) {
    return $item->id !== $id;
});
$collection->prepend($matched->first());
```

Comment: Is this one query? Does Category::find($id) count as a second one?

Comment: It is two queries, but you're not merging arrays this way. It's a constant time operation to prepend.

Comment: Is it better to prepend than to merge performance wise? I always assumed less queries == better

Comment: It would depend on the size of the collection, I've added another method that uses one query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Only one query

```
$categories = Category::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
$categories = $categories->where('id', $imageCategoryId)->merge($categories)
```

or

```
$categories->prepend($categories->where('id', $imageCategoryId)->first())->unique()
```

Comment: Both yours and DigitalDrifter's code works exactly like I wanted it too but I am wondering which would be better performance wise or does it not matter much?

Comment: In my code only one query need. It is more good experience then many query